# Can't create new project with Mobile SDK 3.3 with Cordova 5.0

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I recently upgraded my Cordova installation to 5.0.0 - now I'm trying to create project using forcedroid and getting the following error

```
Copying template files...
Project successfully created.
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugi
n" via git clone
Installing "com.salesforce" for android
Failed to install 'com.salesforce':CordovaError: Plugin doesn't support this pro
ject's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 3.6.4, failed version requireme
nt: 5.0.0
```

How do I resolve this issue? I want to use 5.0 to take advantage of the newer plugins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a known issue with Mobile SDK 3.3 - it will NOT work with Cordova version 5.0 (only Cordova 4.x is supported).

If you have to use Cordova 5.0, please upgrade to the latest version of Mobile SDK - 4.0

This has been discussed [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/1016) as well.

Comment: thx for the link